# Disadvantage using ODBC for Quickbooks to Salesforce

Tags: integration, quickbooks

Is there any disadvantage using ODBC for Quickbooks desktop to Salesforce? We are looking for something useful for the Integration of Quickbooks to Salesforce, I know this might be a duplicate question except using the ODBC. We are thinking to use ODBC to generate the records from Quickbooks, would this be a good Idea or should we use a different approach?

Comment: Unless you're intent on reinventing the wheel, I recommend you look at the App available from the App Exchange that integrates Quick Books data into SF. I know of a number of clients who use it successfully in their Orgs.

Comment: I was looking at the App Exchange a while ago. :) However by keeping myself researching I just learned that there is an SDK for Quickbooks Desktop. It also has a Web Connector that I think might help to integrate it to Salesforce. I'm just confirming if that is for long time support.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I'd think the folks at Intuit would be the ones to try and confirm the long term support with. From what little I know of OBDC it seems more suited to a copy/paste approach, but I confess to only having cursory knowledge of it. Off hand, my initial thoughts had been why OBDC? Were you looking to export periodically as a batch CSV then upload via a DataLoader type utility or more of a streaming update solution instead?

Comment: I also thought of that. Streaming update would be better instead of exporting records and uploading them. The problem with the OBDC, not sure, you have to export it meaning you have to do it manually. It is more efficient if you have a tool or way to get the records automatically without having exporting the data and upload it using DataLoader.

Comment: Agreed. Was just asking for clarification.

Comment: That would be one of its disadvantage. I think it is also possible that the `.csv` file can be modified once it was extracted to its source. Would it be a good idea, especially if it involves financial reports?

Comment: Any database can be modified or extended once it's extracted depending on the permissions set for it in the new location. I wouldn't recommend allowing it when setting up the database. Typically there would be a reference ID (the Quicken transaction ID) that would be used to sync between the two databases and SF would assign a new record ID for the equivalent Quicken transaction record ID.